# Logging module: too many open file descriptors

Tags: python, linux, logging

I am using Python `logging` module to print logs to a file, but I encountered the issue that "too many open file descriptors", I did remember to close the log file handlers, but the issue was still there.

Below is my code

```
class LogService(object):
    __instance = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.__logger = logging.getLogger('ddd')
        self.__handler = logging.FileHandler('/var/log/ddd/ddd.log')
        self.__formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
        self.__handler.setFormatter(self.__formatter)
        #self.__logger.addHandler(self.__handler)

    @classmethod
    def getInstance(cls):
        if cls.__instance == None:
            cls.__instance = LogService()

        return cls.__instance

    # log Error
    def logError(self, msg):
        self.__logger.addHandler(self.__handler)
        self.__logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        self.__logger.error(msg)
        # Remember to close the file handler
        self.closeHandler()

    # log Warning
    def logWarning(self, msg):
        self.__logger.addHandler(self.__handler)
        self.__logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        self.__logger.warn(msg)
        # Remember to close the file handler
        self.closeHandler()

    # log Info
    def logInfo(self, msg):
        self.__logger.addHandler(self.__handler)
        self.__logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.__logger.info(msg)
        # Remember to close the file handler
        self.closeHandler()

    def closeHandler(self):
        self.__logger.removeHandler(self.__handler)
        self.__handler.close()
```

And after running this code for a while, the following showed that there were too many open file descriptors.

```
[root@my-centos ~]# lsof | grep ddd | wc -l
11555
```

Comment: Please show the actual exception, with traceback, instead of just describing it vaguely. (I doubt the actual error refers to "file descriptions".)

Comment: *Tip:* Python is not Java. Don't try writing Python code using Java approaches :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I think you are probably right, I was a Java coder before.:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No no. The usage is far simpler

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()

logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")
logger.info("test")
logger.debug("test")
```

In your case you are appending the handler in every logging operation, which is at least overkill.

Check the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

Each time you log anything, you add another instance of the handler.

Yes, you close it every time. But this just means it takes slightly longer to blow up. Closing it doesn't remove it from the logger.

The first message, you have one handler, so you open one file descriptor and then close it.

The next message, you have two handlers, so you open two file descriptors and close them.

The next message, you open three file descriptors and close them.

And so on, until you're opening more file descriptors than you're allowed to, and you get an error.

To solution is just to not do that.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give the sample code per this case?

Comment: If you just remove the `self.__logger.addHandler(self.__handler)` and `self.closeHandler()` in all of your methods, this error will go away. You probably _also_ want to remove the `setLevel(…)` calls, because there's no point in having logging levels if you set the level to allow each message as you try to log it. And then you're left with nothing but the default implementation, which means you can scrap your overrides entirely. In other words, the best sample code is no code at all. As in Tasos's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, my spider project, with lib "httpx", "scheduler", crash after runing a few days,
throw `SystemError: (libev) error creating signal/async pipe: Too many open files.`

At begining, I suspicious httpx and scheduler, finnaly I spot this question page. I realized I write `logging.getLogger(__name__)` in class `__init__()` method and class was called by scheduler, that results logger instance increases and won't be deleted while scheduler thread is runing.