# Python memory consumption causes to crash web-socket connection

Tags: python

Me and my friend have been trying to solve this code for about a week now with no success. We would appreciate some feedback from experienced programmers.

We have developed below code to connect to a web-socket. Our python script runs smoothly for 7 hours, but after 7 hours it crashes. We got "Error to many open files" couple of times. I have searched stackoverflow for a while to find smilar mistake in coding but we couldn't relate to our actual problem.

We also watch closely proc/"pid of our python script"/fd for open pipes. Whenever it reached to 1024 the websocket connection dies. We edited ulimit -n to increased the limit also but still script dies.

I am sharing the below code, I would really appreciate if you guys can give us some feedback in order for us to solve our longlasting headache.

```
import time
import datetime
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

from bt import Bt

from app import db
from app.models import LOG_HISTORY, BOOKING_ORDERS, BOOKING_CANCELLING, 
add_row, delete_rows

import config

logger = config.Logger('bt log websocket.log')

def get_authenticateWss():
authenticated_wss = Bt(key=config.socket_api_key, 
secret=config.socket_api_secret)
authenticated_wss.start()

while not authenticated_wss.conn.connected.is_set():
    time.sleep(1)

authenticated_wss.authenticate()
time.sleep(5)

return authenticated_wss


def main(authenticated_wss):
while authenticated_wss.conn.connected.is_set():
    booking_orders = BOOKING_ORDERS.query.all()
    for booking_order in booking_orders:
        payload = {
            'cid': booking_order.cid,
            'symbol': 't%s' % booking_order.symbol.split(":") . 
[-1].strip(),
            'type': "EXCHANGE LIMIT",
            'amount': str(booking_order.amount),
            'price': str(booking_order.price),
            'hidden': 1
        }

        authenticated_wss.new_order(**payload)
        logger.info("Creating the Order: %s" % str(payload))
        db.session.delete(booking_order)

        if float(booking_order.amount) >= 0:
            add_row(LOG_HISTORY, [datetime.datetime.now(), 
booking_order.symbol, "Buy Order", str(payload)])
        else:
            add_row(LOG_HISTORY, [datetime.datetime.now(), 
booking_order.symbol, "Selling Order", str(payload)])

        time.sleep(5)

    booking_cancels = BOOKING_CANCELLING.query.all()
    for booking_cancel in booking_cancels:
        payload = {
            'id': booking_cancel.order_id,
            'cid': booking_cancel.order_cid,
            'cid_date': booking_cancel.create_mts
        }

        authenticated_wss.cancel_order(**payload)
        logger.info("Cancelling the Order: %s" % str(payload))
        db.session.delete(booking_cancel)

        add_row(LOG_HISTORY, [datetime.datetime.now(), 
booking_cancel.symbol, "Cancelling Order", str(payload)])
        time.sleep(5)

        # time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
delete_rows(BOOKING_ORDERS)
delete_rows(BOOKING_CANCELLING)

while True:
    logger.info("-------------- START ------------------")
    authenticated_wss = get_authenticateWss()
    try:
        main(authenticated_wss)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
    finally:
        logger.info("---------- STOP -----------------")
        authenticated_wss.stop()
```

Comment: I think your problem may be connected to the use of the logger. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099038/logging-module-too-many-open-file-descriptors,  but honestly that's just the part that makes the most sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, let me test it without the logs, I will post the update here.

Comment: Actually we have taken look at versions that there is no logging and by then it did not work also.

Answer (score 1):

We have solved the issue, it was totally web-socket compatibility issue. We have updated the version of the module.